# Moving all matching files containing spaces and appended different text with wildcards in bash

Tags: bash, unix, rename, wildcard, mv

I have a directory that generates a report daily and I'm writing a script that will move the old report to the trash and rename it just before generating the next report.

e.g. Directory

```
File Report - Sat 16-01-2016.txt
```

As the files always are generated with the same constant 'File\ Report - ' e.g.

```
File Report - Tue 12-01-2016.txt
File Report - Wed 13-01-2016.txt
File Report - Thur 14-01-2016.txt
File Report - Fri 15-01-2016.txt
```

I thought I could use some bash code like this e.g.

```
mv -f ~/Desktop/File\ Report\*.txt ~/.Trash/"Old File Report".txt
```

However I would like to just add the word "Old" to the front of the file whilst keeping whatever day and date comes after. e.g.

```
File Report - Tue 12-01-2016.txt
```

would become

```
Old File Report - Tue 12-01-2016.txt
```

I thought I could use a variable and store the file name in it. I'm not sure how to code this but it would be something like this.

```
OLD=$(echo ~/Desktop/'File Report - '*.txt)
mv -f ~/Desktop/File\ Report\*.txt ~/.Trash/"Old "$OLD.txt
```

I know this is very wrong syntax. I'm currently reading a few of the man pages including `find` to see if something like that would be better for grabbing the file name to store it into a variable.

Comment: Take a look at `rename` command.

Comment: Thank you I just found that, looking now!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic shell loop:

```
for report in ~/Desktop/'File Report'*.txt; do
  mv "$report" ~/.Trash/"Old ${report##*/}"
done
```

The loop variable will contain the file's full path; we trim the directory part from the destination file name with the shell's built-in `${variable##prefix}` string replacement mechanism.

As an aside, if you wanted to assign the old name to another variable, you don't need `echo` for that.

```
old=$report
```

You should not use uppercase variable names, as those are reserved for the shell's own variables (`PATH`, `PS1`, etc).

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you really need to loop through the file results.  i'd use `find` and try something like this.

```
cd ~/REPORT_FOLDER
find . -name 'File Report*.txt' -exec mv {} '~/.Trash/Old {}.txt'
```

or to take the results and put them into an actual `for` loop:

```
cd ~/REPORT_FOLDER
for report in $( find . -name 'File Report*.txt'); do
  mv $report ~/.Trash/"Old $report"
done
```

Comment: The `find` command is overkill if the files are all in the same directory, and wrong if there are subdirectories with files which should not be moved. Just loop over a simple wildcard match.

Comment: Also, not quoting the file name is broken; you *know* the file names contain spaces, so they *have* to be quoted.

Comment: And as nearly always, the `cd` is useless. The shell can cope very well with arbitrary paths to file names; a fact which your script already depends on.